# Java - WebSocket + mTLS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket, mtls

I am trying to implement an app with WebSocket + mTLS in Java Spring Boot. I have set up a WebSocket config like this:

```java
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
...

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyWebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private final MyWebsocketHandler myHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        var registry = webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(myHandler, "/api/ws");
    }
}
```

I have also set the truststore variables in application.properties like this:

```
server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:truststore/client-truststore.p12
server.ssl.trust-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
```

Now, when I try to connect to this endpoint, I get the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

This failure only occurs on the websocket endpoint; when I use a regular controller for the same truststore, it works. So there is nothing wrong with the certificate. Instead, **I suspect that the wss security filter chain logic is wrongly setup**.

The reason why I believe this is the following configuration code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSocketSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import({MyWebSocketConfig.class})
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    AuthorizationManager<Message<?>> authorizationManager(MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.Builder messages) {
        messages
                .simpDestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyMessage().permitAll();
        return messages.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
                {
                    try {
                        authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                                .requestMatchers("/api/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .and()
                                .x509()
                                .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                if (username.equals("localhost")) {
                    return new User(username, "",
                            AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
                }
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This code should, to my knowledge, call the userDetailsService() method as part of the websocket connect request, which would then be able to extract certificate information (which in turn would enable mTLS). However, the websocket connect request completely bypasses the userDetailsService() method call and just throws the above error again:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

When I switch the request type from wss to https (i.e. wss://localhost:1234/api/ws -> https://localhost:1234/api/ws), this method is hit as expected.

With all of this said, I reiterate: **I suspect that the wss security filter chain logic is wrongly setup**. It seems like either the certificate check preempts my SecurityFilterChain bean or that the SecurityFilterChain Bean configuration doesn't work for wss.

My question, therefore, is: How do I fix websocket + mTLS for java Spring Boot?